# Better way to deal with java generics handling?

Tags: java, generics

Have a metod:

```
public <T> T foo(Class<T> type);
```

When I call it like:

```
String s = foo(String.class);
```

everything is fine. This also works:

```
Set s = foo(Set.class);
```

However, the following does not compile:

```
Set<String> s = foo(Set.class);    // compilation error
```

so I fix it with something stupid like:

```
Set<?> tmp = foo(Set.class);
Set<String> s = (Set<String>) tmp;
```

I can't change the signature of `foo()`. Is there better way to make this assignment that I am missing?

### EDIT

For some strange reason, it is not clear what I am doing here. So, method `foo` here is a method that takes some input plus `Class<T>`. It than takes the input and creates an instance of given class. So, the real signature of `foo` may be:

```
public <T> T parseStringToClass(String input, Class<T> targetClass);
```

And the usage may be:

```
Integer value = parseStringToClass("123", Integer.class);
```

There is nothing unusual here - it's fairly common signature for any parser and converter out there.

Comment: This isn't new in Java 8, and more or less the answer is "no, there isn't; erasure doesn't work the way you want it to."

Comment: @LouisWasserman maybe you can please explain? Isn't that the purpose of SO?

Comment: @игор in Java 8 your code Set<String> s = foo(Set.class); with warnings, but compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get any help from the compiler, if that's what you're looking for. As has been observed in comments, generics don't work the way you want them to.

The best you can do is combine your cast with your invocation of `foo()`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Added to keep my Eclipse happy
Set<String> s = (Set<String>) parseStringToClass("Set<String>, Hello World, Goodnight Irene", Set.class);
```

This of course relies on the ability of `parseStringToClass` to recognize that it's being handed a `String` that has multiple `String`s inside it, and that they should be converted into a `Set`, itself a nontrivial task.

You'll no doubt observe that the compiler doesn't have any idea whether the `Set` being returned is a `Set<String>`. That information just isn't available.

Comment: If the downvoter would care to comment, what exactly is the complaint?

Answer (score -1):

Since java's generics are erased, `List<String>` and `List<Object>` are both represented by one class: `List`. If you really need to represent an instantiated generic type at runtime you can use [Guava's TypeToken](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained#typetoken) to do so, but this has quite a bit of overhead and is not always as useful as you might think.

Ultimately it depends on what the `foo` method does on how to solve this in the most elegant way.

Answer (score -1):

According to the link below, you can't get the literal for the generic type
http://goo.gl/6CtqGt

What I'd suggest you to do if you really need to use one method is:

```
Set<String> set = foo(new HashSet<String>().getClass());
```

It's very ugly but it works.

Comment: PS.: I'm on my phone, later I'll edit my answer and improve it.

Comment: Eclipse complains about that. It says, "Type safety: The expression of type capture#1-of ? extends HashSet needs unchecked conversion to conform to Set<String>". This is because the class literal does not carry all of the information necessary for the compiler to enforce type safety.

Comment: even if this compiles, creating new `HashSet` just to satisfy the compiler is a bit too much :)

Comment: @erick-g-hagstrom wich java version are you using? Here it worked on java 8.